# npm start issues with react-scripts 3.4.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I know this question has already been asked but I can't find a solution. When I run `npm start` inside a react project, I always get the same logs (see below). The only solution given is to uninstall `node_modules` and re-do the installation. I also tried to clear the cache. Nothing worked.

Some people solved this problem upgrading to `react-scripts 3.4.0` (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8490) but that didn't work for me. The only solution I have now is to downgrade `react-scripts` to version `2.1.8` by using `npm install react-scripts@2.1.8`. But it's not a good solution because I have to work on a framework that uses the latest version.

here are the logs :

```
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.43.27/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\fthom\Desktop\temp\my-app\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
Starting the development server...

events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fthom\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-21T10_59_13_574Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Add the default variables in the machines PATH:

C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem

[Screenshot of variables location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEP0z.png)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the path worked for me.
Just to add, on the above solution for those who didn't know how to change the path (same as me) and some more details.

Here is my way on how to change environment variables on Windows 10:

- Open the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system environment variables”
- Click the <kbd>Environment Variables…</kbd> button.
- Go on system variables and under variables find PATH, mark it and click <kbd>EDIT</kbd>.
- On the end of the list add paths - you can simply click on new or on the empty field on the end of list:
  `C:\Windows\system32` 
  `C:\Windows` 
  `C:\Windows\System32\Wbem`
- Remember to have the npm paths as well: 
  `C:\Program Files\nodejs` 
  `C:\Users{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- Set the environment variables as needed.
- The New button adds an additional variable. ...
- Dismiss all of the dialogs by choosing <kbd>OK</kbd>. Your changes are saved!
- Restart the computer.

Now it should work!

Answer (score 1):

It took me two days to resolve this issue.

Its because of the incompatibility issue of react-scripts so try installing different versions like:

This worked for me:

`npm install --save react-scripts@2.1.8`

This one did work for many as they claim:

`npm install --save react-scripts@3.3.0`

It should work as it did to me after an arduous struggle.

Comment: Installing react scripts 3.3.0 worked for my NextJS project. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes on windows, I get the same error message randomly if the npm cache is somehow messed up.

Try to run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Delete the **node_modules** folder and the **package.lock.json** file and run `npm install` afterward.

Comment: Hi,
thanks but i had already tried this. I retried however, but it still didn't work. I have a dual boot computer, so i switched on linux to make some npm and react tests, it fully worked there. I am going to fully uninstall nodeJS and NPM from my windows, this is the last thing i can try before a full reboot, because i really need to work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system environment
   variables
2. Click the Environment Variables Button.
3. Go on system variables and under variables find PATH, mark it and click EDIT.
4. On the end of the list add paths - you can simply click on new or on the empty field
5. Go to your react app folder then go to `node_modules` and then go to `bin` folder and then copy url
6. Paste your url in new path